# In Set up project context, what does the options "Localized Resourses from <project name>" & "Content files from <project name>" mean?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, setup-project, setup-deployment, setuptools

I am creating a set up project for a windows C# application.  I understood the meaning of the option "primary output from {project name}".

> But I **didnt** understand what is the
>   purpose of the options "Localized
>   Resourses from {project name}" and
>   "Content files from {project name}".

What are these localized resourses, content files.

I want to understand in greater detail, regarding these 2 options of set up project. Can anyone kindly let me know this.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 6):

Its a good question. Even I had same doubt few days back and I found that information. Even you asked only about two things but I'm giving information about all the items available in that box. Here it is:

**Documentation Files**: C# source files can be annotated with special comments (starting with ///). The C# compiler strips out this information to build an XML documentation file. Visual Studio .NET is able to use these files to provide documentation tooltips.
You would include such output when building a Setup project whose purpose is to install software components on a developer's machine. You would not normally include this output group in anything intended to be installed on an end user's machine.

**Localized Resources:** Any satellite resources created for localized versions of an application will be in this output group. You would include this group for any project in which you have created localized resources.

**Debug Symbols:** When compiling with debugging enabled, the compiler produces a separate file containing the symbolic information required by the debugger (a .pdb file). This output group contains that information.
You would not normally want to redistribute debug symbols. However, sometimes you will not be able to reproduce problems on a developer's machine, in which case it can be useful to install debug symbols on a target machine in order to try and diagnose problems. You would include this group when building a special debugging installation.

**Content Files:** Project files that do not get compiled will appear in this group. (This will include any project item with aBuildAction property of Content.)
You usually want to include this output group for web applications because .aspx files and graphics are all classed as Content. For other applications, you usually wouldn't include this group.

**Source Files:** This group includes all of the source code in the project.
You would very rarely include this group. However, if you are diagnosing a problem in situ, this, in conjunction with the Debug Symbols group, would provide a way of installing everything required to do source-level debugging on a machine without having to copy the entire solution across.

For the benefit of other users I've added all the other items too. I hope this information gives you enough knowledge.